# Skip Form Validation while using codeigniter 3 paginaiton

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, pagination

I have a search form which accepts 7 different inputs and use those values to query data from 5 different tables. Fetched rows are returned to the CodeIgniter controller to be displayed in a view but with a pagination.

Along with other input specific validation, I am also checking that at least one value out of 7 fields in provided by the user for search. If not then we throw an error.

The following code works fine, it queries data and show pagination also but it breaks when I click on page 2 of pagination links because then controller reloads the search form and perform the form validation which fails.

Controller Code to perform validation and get data and paginate:

```
public function search_metadata_database()
{
    $arr = array();
    $data = $this->input->post();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value)
        {
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    if(count($arr) < 1)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('metadata_search_message', 'Please provide atleast one input!');
        redirect('Metadata/search_metadata_view');
    } 
    else 
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_search');
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_form');
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                $arr[$key] = $this->get_master_id_by_name($key,$value);
            }

            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('Metadata/search_metadata_database');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->metadata_model->fetch_metadata_record_count($arr);
            $config['per_page'] = "2";
            $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
            $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
            $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['first_link'] = false;
            $config['last_link'] = false;
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
            $data['songList'] 
            = $this->metadata_model->fetch_metadata_record($arr,$config["per_page"], $data['page']);
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_search');
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_pagination',$data);
        }
    }   
}
```

Instead of displaying the second page of pagination (next 2 rows), I am getting redirected to following views:

```
$this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_search');
$this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_form');
```

Along with the message:'Please provide at least one input!'

How can I skip form validation while I am navigating through pagination links while also make it work when someone click on search button ?

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run() && isset($_POST['submit']))

Answer (score 0):

First of all Just create a library in application > library folder

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function curr_page() {
        return $this->cur_page;
    }
}
```

after it just use this below code in your controller.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE && $this->curr_page <= 1)
        {
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_search');
            $this->load->view('pages/metadataview/metadata_form');
        }
```